# C# So how does this hexadecimal stuff work?

Tags: c#, binary, hex, size, bit

I'm doing some entry level programming challenges at codefights.com and I came across the following question. The link is to a blog that has the answer, but it includes the question in it as well. If only it had an explanation...

https://codefightssolver.wordpress.com/2016/10/19/swap-adjacent-bits/

My concern is with the line of code (it is the *only* line of code) below.

```
return (((n & 0x2AAAAAAA) >> 1) | ((n & 0x15555555) << 1)) ;
```

Specifically, I'm struggling to find some decent info on how the "0x2AAAAAAA" and "0x15555555" work, so I have a few dumb questions. I know they represent binary values of 10101010... and 01010101... respectively.

***1. I've messed around some and found out that the number of 5s and As corresponds loosely and as far as I can tell to bit size, but how?***

***2. Why As? Why 5s?***

***3. Why the 2 and the 1 before the As and 5s?***

***4. Anything else I should know about this? Does anyone know a cool blog post or website that explains some of this in more detail?***

Comment: Do you know what hexadecimal actually is?

Comment: So you basically want to know how the hexadecimal system works? It's just numbers, the '0x' at the head telling us that they are noted not using base 10 like our usual decimal system but base 16.  I recommend to just read about numerical systems, starting with good old Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system).

Comment: Then you can work on and read about bit shifting ( `>` is the bit shift operstor). But this does not make sense unless you know about hexadecimal & binary...

Comment: hex A is "1010" in binary, 5 is "0101" in binary, that's all. If you understand the logic - you should understand why you need "1010" and "0101" too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

0x2AAAAAAA is used to get 30 bits, which is the constraint.

Constraints:
0 ≤ n < 2^30.

0x15555555 also represent 30 bits with bits opposite of other number.
I would start with binary number (101010101010101010101010101010) in the calculator and select hex using programmer calculator to show the number in hex.

you can also use 0b101010101010101010101010101010 too, if you like, depending on language.

Comment: Hmm, although I understand the original code, I don&#39;t see how this explains much... Your answer does not pay the TO anything IMHO...

Comment: this answers...Why As? Why 5s?

Answer (score 3):

`0x2AAAAAAA` is `00101010101010101010101010101010` in 32 bits binary,

`0x15555555` is ‭`00010101010101010101010101010101‬` in 32 bits binary.

Note that the problem specifies `Constraints: 0 ≤ n < 2^30`. For this reason the highest two bits can be `00`.

The two hex numbers have been "built" starting from their binary representation, that has a particular property (that we will see in the next paragraph).

Now... We can say that, given the constraint, `x & 0x2AAAAAAA` will return the even bits of `x` (if we count the bits as first, second, third... the second bit is even), while `x & 0x15555555` will return the odd bits of `x`. By using `<< 1` and `>> 1` you move them of one step. By using `|` (or) you re-merge them.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about the syntax of 0x2AAAAAAA and 0x15555555. I understand the logic just fine.

Comment: @TomBuck "syntax"? It's how hex numbers are written.

Comment: @TomBuck They are hex numbers. `0x` means that the number that follows is a hex number, so it can use 0-9, A-F, a-f as digits, and there is a convention that the digits are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f (or uppercase variant), with 0xa = 10 decimal, and 0xf = 15 decimal. From this, 0x10 = 16 decimal.

Comment: I guess I was assuming it somehow more complicated. So those are just the Hex representations of 1431655765 and 2863311530 then? (0101010101... and 1010101010... in binary)

Comment: @TomBuck The base10 values are totally irrelevant. They are the hex representation of 00101010101010101010101010101010 and 00010101010101010101010101010101‬ . **first** the person that wrote the solution wrote the two binary numbers that had the property he wanted, **then** he converted in hex number (because old versions of C# can't use diretly binary number, changed from C# 7.0). Note that you can go from binary to hex by grouping the digits 4 at a time. 0000 = 0, 0001 = 1, ... 1110 = e, 1111 = f without going through decimal.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you.